# Titanium android slide animation compresses view

Tags: android, animation, titanium

I have a slide out menu on android, working fine so far.

The only problem is that the animation compresses optically the width (about 5-10 DiP) of that view while sliding, so some elements in that view became thinner or will be cut off when to close the border.

```
var leftMenu = Ti.UI.createView({
       backgroundColor : 'black',
       top : 0,
       left : -210,
       width : 240,
       zIndex : 1000,
});
```

Inside of it, I do have a tableview with sections, the works.
and a view as a button, as a toggle to open and close. this is visible when closed.

The animation itself is pretty straight forward

```
var animateLeft = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
       left : 0,
       duration : 500
});
```

Needless to say, it works flawlessly on an iPhone.

I'm interested in why this compression/clipping effect takes place, and how to circumvent/prevent it. does anyone know something about this?

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this? I'm having the same issue.